# Android notification click loses place in stack

Tags: android, notifications

When I launch a notification from the "second page" of my app and then close (hide) the app by going to my home screen, I can get directly back to the second page by clicking the notification.  However, pressing back from this point should, I think, take me back to page one, but it instead closes the app as if it's on the first page.  Am I missing a flag of some type?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start activities they stack on top of each other giving you a history stack, when you start an activity directly there is no history.

Not sure if there is a super easy way to do this but people have [rolled their own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568250/use-a-persistent-notification-to-allow-the-user-to-return-to-running-android-app) but it really seems like their should be a better way to do this ...