# Android: Tell When App Returns to Foreground

Tags: android

I have an activity called `EntranceActivity` which routes to other activities based on a few different parameters.

This `Activity` is `ClearTop`-ed, such that I can `startActivity(...EntranceActivity...)` and re-route through the `EntranceActivity` logic without having to worry about little nuances. It is also the only entrance point to the application when returning to foreground.

I need to be able to determine when this `Activity` is being pushed to the foreground from the `beginning` (from first launch / from being in background) vs when I am routing to it during the app usage. (i.e. from `Activity2` back to `EntranceActivity`)

The following question shows how to determine if the app is in the foreground... but the `EntranceActivity` will only execute when the app is in the `Foreground`, so that does not seem to be what I'm looking for.

[How can I tell if android app is running in the foreground?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504632/how-can-i-tell-if-android-app-is-running-in-the-foreground)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting this to work by adding another `EntranceActivity` which is the only entry point to the app, and redirects to the `ViewDispatcherActivity` (the old `EntranceActivity`).

Now I can continue to clear-top to `ViewDispatcherActivity` as needed during the app, while having some `Return-To-Foreground` logic (because the user never returns to `EntranceActivity` during normal app operation)

EntranceActivity (the only app entry point)

onCreate:

```
if (ShouldShowAccessActivity()) { startActivityForResult( new Intent(EntranceActivity.this,AccessActivity.class)); return; }

//go to view dispatcher to further branch off.
startActivityForResult(new Intent(EntranceActivity.this,ViewDispatcherActivity.class));
```

Comment: I wonder if you could expand on the "Return-To-Foreground" logic you mentioned :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this with refcounting ... in your base activity (you have one right? ;-) ), [increment the value](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) in the onResume method, and decrement it in the onPause method. If the value is non-zero, then your app is visible :-)

Comment: I do have a base activity, but ref-counting wont quite accomplish what I need. I've added my solution to this page. Sorry if my question was not clear enough. Cheers!