# How to detect if your android app is in the foreground (API 21)

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-5.0-lollipop

when receiving a GCM message, the behaviour of my app depends on if it is in the foreground or not. Prior to API 21 I used the following:

```
Boolean onForeground = this.getPackageName().equalsIgnoreCase(
            ((ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE))
            .getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName()
);
```

Now getRunningTasks() is deprecated and behaving differently on API 21, what would be the best way on API 21 to detect if my app is in the foreground?

Google recommends

```
public ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo getTaskInfo ()
```

but I do not see how I can get the information I need from there.

Thank you in advance.

---

**Edit:** As proposed by @CommonsWare and @Chris Stratton, I could keep track of onResume/onPause states. A app-crash cause by a WebView (content outside my control) would leave the system in the wrong state. Sending a GCM in such wrong state would cause an other crash confusing the user (he/she is not doing anything at that moment with my app).

I am therefore looking for another solution.
(I am using Fragments and only have 1 activity, so implementing this would be trivial)

Comment: Use an event bus to let the UI layer of your app know that the GCM message was received. Have the UI layer (activities/fragments) of your app register and unregister from the bus as they come and go from the foreground. Have a means of determining if the UI layer did not handle the event, and do your background processing (e.g., raise a `Notification`).

Comment: I have samples implementing this pattern for three event buses: [`LocalBroadcastManager`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/LocalBroadcastManager), Square's [Otto](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/Otto), and greenrobot's [EventBus](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/GreenRobot).

Comment: In other words, an Activity is in the foreground between onResume() and onPause(), and an Application is when *any one* of its Activities is - something you can track by having them all call or mesage into a common component.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, it was something I did consider but would like to avoid as I have a webview that sometimes causes a crash of the app (due to the content, outside my control). such situation would leave the wrong state. (Will update my question)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an [ordered broadcast approach](http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/08/11/activity-notification-ordered-broadcast.html) where you

- Create a `BroadcastReceiver` registered in your manifest which does the background behavior
- Dynamically register a `BroadcastReceiver` in your activity with a positive priority (the default is `0`), making sure to register it in `onStart()`/`onResume()` and unregistering it in `onStop()`/`onPause()` - this does the foreground behavior and should call [abortBroadcast()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#abortBroadcast()) to ensure the manifest registered `BroadcastReceiver` is not called

Your GCM receiver can then use [sendOrderedBroadcast()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast(android.content.Intent)) to send a broadcast (preferably with a custom action that both your other `BroadcastReceiver`s register for) which will be received by the dynamically registered receiver if it exists and the manifest registered receiver if it does not exist.

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I am looking for. Didn't even know about the sendOrderedBroadcast(), so will have some reading to do tomorrow. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I detect using `getRunningAppProcesses`

```
boolean isOnForeground = true;
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH)
{
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses)
    {
        if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND)
        {
            for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList)
            {                                 if(activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName()))
                {
                    isOnForeground = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
else
{
     List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
     ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
                if(componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName()))
     {
          isOnForeground = false;
     }
}
```

Comment: An application process can have foreground priority/importance even when not in the foreground. The OP wants to know if their application is actually in the foreground so this will not work. E.g. A process with no visible Activity, which has a Service that has used startForeground would have foreground importance. Also, aren't you returning the opposite of what you want?