# android Notification - how to not show in foreground

Tags: android, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

hey all i got a tough problem and need advice.  I have constructed a notification manually after recieving a FCM data payload.  This is how the notification gets created both in foreground and background since its a data payload:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {


    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {

        String msg = remoteMessage.getData().get("message");
        sendNotification(msg);
    }

private PendingIntent createIntent(String msg) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SportsActivity.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString(Constants.KEY_GO_TO_TAB, Constants.KEY_DASHBOARD_HOCKEY_SCORE_TAB);
    intent.putExtras(b);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    return pendingIntent;
}

private void sendNotification( String messageBody) {
    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText(messageBody))
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.hockey_brand))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(createIntent(messageBody));

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

}

it seems to function fine. The issue im having is i want the notification to NOT SHOW in when the app is in the foreground. is there not a way to do this without scanning the activity task ? as this requires a permission

i've read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414171/how-to-detect-when-an-android-app-goes-to-the-background-and-come-back-to-the-fo) but this how to know you've  went from foreground to background.  also  android.permission.GET_TASKS is deprecated and REAL_GET_TASKS permission is not for third party either. I simply want to know at any given time that the user is either in foreground or background so i know if i should show a notification or not.  I wonder if firebase itself has something.  When you send a "Notification payload" from the firebase console if the app is not in the foreground is does not show in the notification panel so there should be a way to do this.

Comment: maybe [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39589766/5015207) is helpful?

Comment: thanks even though android.permission.GET_TASKS is a deprecated permission i believe. tell me if i am wrong. I dont even see it on the list of permssions anymore. and im supporting api 19 so i cant use getAppTasks(); do you know if android.permission.GET_TASKS is a dangerous permission ?

Comment: The code snippet by Juozas Kontvainis does not seem to need any permission. I suppose it's because it just tries to obtain information about its own application.

Comment: thank you so much for helping me with this. i was focusing so much on GET_TASKS that i did not see this one which so far works great !. its actually a hidden gem , no ones seeing this way i wonder if there is a downside. but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can choose not to show your notification when your app is in foreground by implementing [Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html)
in your Application.

Then you can check if your app is in foreground or background.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504632/how-can-i-tell-if-android-app-is-running-in-the-foreground/39589766#39589766)