# How can I create an Android notification from Phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

what I want to make is a notification from Phonegap,
I want to launch this from a request made in polling via js to a page that returns a JSON,
after the call end I want to parse the JSON and launch the Android notification.
The application have to run in background.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this notification plugin which might work for you need:

[Statusbar Notification Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/StatusBarNotification)

For `The application have to run in background` you might want to look in these posts:

[How can I tell if Android app is running in the foreground?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504632/how-can-i-tell-if-android-app-is-running-in-the-foreground)

or

[How to detect if any of my activity is front-most and visible to user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136187/how-to-detect-if-any-of-my-activity-is-front-most-and-visible-to-user)

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to consider Google's C2DM (Cloud to device messaging) to do a push notification. You could push your json to your app, parse it and then create the notification you want. This will avoid needing to implement polling on the device and killing battery life if done properly.

https://github.com/awysocki/C2DM-PhoneGap