# Activity Manager Task list order is wrong on Galaxy S Ii

Tags: android, galaxy

In our app, we check if an task is running in foreground using this:
[How to detect if any of my activity is front-most and visible to user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136187/how-to-detect-if-any-of-my-activity-is-front-most-and-visible-to-user)

Our activity invokes the browser with a link. When we come back to our app, the manager still thinks the browser is running foreground...

When I try the same with the galaxy tab 7", our app is on top. This is the expected behavior.
I have tried with Galaxy S also, and the have the expected behavior.
The problem shows up on the Galaxy S 2 only so far.

Is this a device/os bug? What is the work around?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a device/os bug?

Presumably.

> What is the work around?

Whatever problem you think you are solving via `ActivityManager` can probably be solved better some other way, so I would advise you to aim to get rid of your `ActivityManager` dependency.